# Had to click browser back double times to go the previous url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am facing a trouble with browser back button. In our application we have the url's in this way

/team-list 
/home
So let's say i am on /home and navigate to /team-list we have certain query params being added to the url and this the url which looks like after query params /team-list?search=&limit=35. Now when I click on the browser back button it first goes to /team-list (removes the query params) and then on clicking for the second time it goes to the /home page.

I need help how to go /home on first click instead of clicking for two times. We are using ng-route for routing.

Comment: @Pete I am sorry but I couldn't get you're point of premanent redirect. We need the params which are being added as those are used for url sharing after a search is perfomed. Browser is caching two url's one with /team-list and the other one with query parms /team-lsit?search=&limit

Comment: @Pete Sorry my bad i should have written that point